# TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' tkinter

Tags: tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy empezando con el Python y estoy intentando hacer una simple GUI pero tengo un problema a la hora de recoger la información de los campos de texto. me da un **TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'** He estado revisando documentación y no se exactamente donde está el error. Este es mi código:

```
def populate_main_window(frm_main):
    """Populate the main window of this program. In other words, put
    the labels, text entry boxes, and buttons into the main window.

    Parameter
        frm_main: the main window
    Return: nothing
    """
    url = tk.StringVar
    format = tk.StringVar

    # Create de labels
    lbl_url = tk.Label(frm_main, text="URL:")
    lbl_format = tk.Label(frm_main, text="(V)ideo or (A)udio: ")

    # Create de entrys
    ent_url = tk.Entry(frm_main, width=30, textvariable=url)
    ent_format = tk.Entry(frm_main, width=1, textvariable=format)

    # Create download buttom
    btn_download = tk.Button(frm_main, text="Download")

    lbl_url.grid(column=0, row=0)
    lbl_format.grid(column=0, row=1)
    ent_url.grid(column=1, row=0)
    ent_format.grid(column=1, row=1)
    btn_download.grid(column=1, row=3)

    def download():
        yt = YouTube(url.get())
        if format.lower() == 'v':
            download_video(yt)
            tk.Message(frm_main, text="Video downloaded")

        elif format.lower() == 'a':
            download_audio(yt)

    btn_download.config(command=download)
```

Comment: Se te olvidó poner los parentesis a la derecha de los tk.StringVar! Cambia estas lineas `url = tk.StringVar format = tk.StringVar` por estas `url = tk.StringVar() format = tk.StringVar()`

Comment: Gracias, eso resolvió mi error. Ahora tengo el problema de que no puedo obtener el valor de las StringVar mediante el método get() ya que el resultado no es ninguna String, es un objeto.  Necesito sacar el valor de url y de format del siguiente código.  Qué debería de cambiar?

`    def download():
        yt = YouTube(url.get())
        if format.get() == 'v':
            download_video(yt)
            tk.Message(frm_main, text="Video downloaded")

        elif format.get() == 'a':
            download_audio(yt)

    btn_download.config(command=download)`

Comment: Eso es raro. Si se trata de un stringvar, .get SIEMPRE devuelve una cadena.